# Ubuntu only boots to emergency mode

Tags: 18.04

I manually updated my Ubuntu 18.04 4.15 kernel to a stable 4.19 version. Rebooted, everything was fine. Then I installed the NVidia 415 driver along with a ppa and after rebooting I only get into emergency mode, booting into default mode also results in emergency mode again. With the given root console I purged all nvidia drivers with purge nvidia* , but that didnt seem to do the trick. Booting into either 4.15 or 4.19 kernel doesnt change anything either. Im new to linux, using it for like a month now.
I have currently 4 ppas installed:
- Google-chrome
- graphics-drivers
- pipelight
- teejee2008

I tried to remove the graphics drivers ppa with add-apt-repository --remove ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa , but It says it doesnt exist because I dont know the exact name of the ppa. I have no internet connection in emergency mode either. Journalctl -xb gives me 1900 lines of system logs, scrolling through it I notices some red lines:
- nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: Pointer to TMDS table invalid
- fsck failed with exit status 4
- Failed to start File System check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/a578589e-55fd-4e98-8478-f04a3a97b30b.

I dont know what to do now since I dont want to mess things up more because I need some files for tomorrow.